# Regexp extract XML attribute value

Tags: python, regex, xml

please, advice how to get xml attribute value with regexp python style.

Here is the example, the extract has to be full match(long story)

```
<method code="ABC">
```

the most I achieved is `(?<=code=\")(.*?)(?=\">)`, but that ignores method part at all

thanks

Comment: Don't parse XML using regex; use a real XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, either you learn the basics of regex syntax and use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), or you have a look at the Python's [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module to parse the xml directly.

If you want to go with a regex, you can test language-specific expressions interactively with online tools, [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for example.

Maybe `<(?P<method>\w*?) (?P<code>\w*?)=\"(?P<value>.*)\">` will do the job.
But once again, as mentioned, extracting data from XML using regex is fragile and very limited.

---

EDIT: Clearer explanation for [3](https://regex101.com/)

EDIT2: Add regex suggestion

Comment: By saying python style, I meant that the application that will process this regular expression expects python regexp syntax. Coding is not an option here, so the only way is to get regular expression working.

Comment: Then you can use the link I provided at the end. It is an online tool that allow to test language specific regex. I will edit my answer so it is clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fabien, I've already did test my regexp on the site you suggested before posting here and asking for solution

Comment: Basic regex suggestion added, you can work on this base.